# ZSH Completion based on previous flag

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I am trying to create a completion where one of my completions will be dynamically generated depending on the values of the other flags. For example

```
local state

_arguments \
  '-f[fabric]:fabric:->fabrics' \
  '-c[containers/application where log resides]:container:->containers' \
  '-l[name of log file]:log:->logs'

case "$state" in
    (fabrics)
        _values 'fabrics' \
          'fab1' \
          'fab2'
    ;;
(containers)
    _values 'containers' \
      'container1' \
      'container2'
    ;;
(logs)
    # show A B C if "-c container1" was entered
    # show D E F if "-c container2" was entered
    # show G if "-c" was not provided yet
esac
```

I am having trouble getting the "-l" flag to be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could inspect the `$words`:

> Completion Special Parameters
>   ...
>   Inside  completion  widgets,  and  any functions called from them, some parameters have special meaning;
>   ...
>   `words`
>   This array contains the words present on the command line currently being edited.
>
> -- [`zshcompwid(1)`: Completion Special Parameters, Completion Widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-words)

We could do the stuff like this:

```
(logs)
    local -i index=${words[(I)-c]}
    local -i ret=0
    if ((index == 0)); then
        _values 'logs' F
        ret=$?
    elif [[ "$words[index+1]" == container1 ]]; then
        _values 'logs' A B C
        ret=$?
    elif [[ "$words[index+1]" == container2 ]]; then
        _values 'logs' D E F
        ret=$?
    fi
    return ret
```

---

To inspect arrays, it is usefull to use the array [Subscript Flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags):

> Subscript Flags
>   If  the  opening  bracket,  or  the  comma in a range, in any subscript expression is directly followed by an opening parenthesis,  the  string up  to the matching closing one is considered to be a list of flags, as in `name[(flags)exp]`.
>
> -- [`zshparam(1)`,  Subscript Flags, Array Subscripts, Array Parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags)

So,`$words[(I)-c]` means `I` "flag" + `-c` as "exp" for `$words` which is "Last matching element's index for "-c" in the array `$word`". For example:

```
 $ tmp=(my-test-command -f flag -c container1 -l)
 $ echo $tmp[(I)-c]
 4
 $ echo $tmp[(I)container1]
 5
 $ tmp=(my-test-command -f flag -c container1 -c container2 -l)
 $ echo $tmp[(I)-c]
 6
```

Comment: This is great! I got it working, but I don't quite understand the first index part. Can you explain what (I) and -c is?

Comment: Updated; I've added some example/usage for inspecting arrays with subscript flags.